# separation of js / css and it's effect on caching

Tags: performance, caching, file-organization

Say I have the following setup:

**Page1.html**

- Includes master.css, page1.css and page1.js

**Page2.html**

- Includes master.css, page2.css and page2.js

I have been told that merging the two js and additional css files would be better for caching? But wouldn't the separate files be cached as well? I don't see how this makes a difference (aside from maintainability maybe - personally I like the separation).

what is the most perform-ant and most sensible way to organize something like this?

*Disclaimer::* Micro optimization is not the issue here - I would like to know what the best practices are before I begin my project so I do not have to revisit this later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit would be:

If the user visits Page1, then Page2, their browser would fetch:

```
Page1.html
-> master.css
-> page1.css
-> page1.js
```

Then, some time later:

```
Page2.html
-> [ no need to re-fetch cached items ]
```

If the page1.css <-> page2.css and page1.js <-> page2.js are substantially similar, that could (worst-case) save two DNS look-ups, and two HTTP negotiations, which could be fairly slow.

At the very least, you're possibly saving having to "listen to" about 1KiB of incoming HTTP headers twice for page2.css and page2.js. (Although all the major browsers will likely chain those requests together.)

Comment: when would separation be desired? say page1.js is 2kb and page2.js is 60kb? is this less a cut-and-dry and more a do-what-works-for-you ??

Comment: ... " "factor out the common stuff" is probably the general rule. Since you have a master.css, I'd assume (hope?) that page1.css and page2.css are actually quite short…? in which case, I'd suggest embedding them directly into the HTML (if they're extremely short) or putting them into master.css (if they don't conflict with one another); likewise, for the JavaScript…

Comment: Other thing to do is ensure the cache headers are set correctly so that the browser avoids the get with 'if-modified-since' for the components on page 2

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to consider here:

- The size of the page1 and page2 files. If they are very small it's probably not worth the extra overhead of a separate http request to put them in individual files.
- The total size of your combined files: Some mobile devices are not keen on caching large files.
- The likelihood of your users hitting both page1 and page2 during their visit to your site.

A side note: If you're worried about the server side organization you can keep the files separated while developing and combine the files into one as a part of your build.

Comment: I (as a general rule of thumb) do have my css and js 'compiled/merged' before it goes to production - I guess my main concern is not the two page example, rather the 30 page example (very large applications) - the individual file size may be small, however the collective can get weighty. But like I mentioned that is a specific case - generally combine the choice files and move on?

Comment: Small addition: In my experience there's typically a difference between js and css resources - especially when developing fairly rich clients: My Javascript code tends to be quite page specific, whereas my css is a lot more reusable (check out [object oriented css](http://oocss.org/)).

Comment: the CSS was just to add to the question - I have not come a crossed any projects where I would need this (small specific css can stay in the global file). the JS portion of it was my main concern. I'm implementing a MVC/P and my view is manipulated heavily by javascript, and each view will have strikingly different features and functionality. I'm in the design phase right now and i'm trying to think of as much reusable functionality as possible.

Comment: To boil it down, I think I would keep the files separated if the combined file has a substantial size (having to load ~1MB of js the first time I'm visiting your site will not leave a positive impression) and it can be divided into smaller (cacheable) files that are loaded "on demand" on your sub pages.

Comment: Another strategy you could think of is "cheating" by preloading resources on otherwise lightweight pages such as a login page that the user is likely to visit before starting your app. This would fill the cache and thereby make the app load faster.

Comment: that last suggestions sounds like it may carry some more merit on the mobile end of life.